# Rails: Find entries by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm running Ruby 2 and Rails 4.

I am creating an app where you can track the calories and macronutrients of each meal entered on a particular day, but I would like the ability to look back at previous days.

I have a table showing what meals have been entered today on my index page through a scope in my model. How would I implement the ability to look back at other days in Rails?

Should I add in a date model or give each meal a datetime? Is there a gem for this sort of thing?

**Meals Model**

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :today, lambda { 
    where("created_at > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day)
    .where("created_at < ?", Time.now.end_of_day) 
  }

  scope :previous, lambda {
    where("created_at < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day) 
  }

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :calories, presence: true, numericality: { only
  validates :protein, numericality: { only_integer: true }
  validates :carbohydrates, numericality: { only_integer: t
  validates :fats, numericality: { only_integer: true }

  belongs_to :user

end
```

**Meals Controller**

```
  def index
    if user_signed_in?
      @todays_meals = current_user.meals.today
      unless current_user.bmr.blank? || current_user.weight.blank? || current_user.protein_intake.blank? || current_user.fat_percentage.blank?
        @remaining_calories = (current_user.bmr) - @todays_meals.sum(:calories)
        @remaining_protein = current_user.protein_intake - @todays_meals.sum(:protein)
        @remaining_fats = (current_user.bmr * current_user.fat_percentage / 900).to_i - @todays_meals.sum(:fats)
        @remaining_carbs = carbs_calculator
        @fat_grams = current_user.fat_percentage * current_user.bmr / 900
        @carb_grams = (carbs_calculator + @todays_meals.sum(:carbohydrates))
      end
    else
      @no_header = true
    end
  end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you could simplify your `today` scope as there's really no way to have something created earlier than the end of today (using standard Rails methods, unless you're manually updating the created_at date).

```
scope :today, -> { 
  where("created_at > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day)
}
```

As for previous days, you can use the following scope to grab them and group them by the day

```
scope :in_the_past_x_days, -> (x) {
  where('meals.created_at > ?', x.days.ago)
  .group("DATE(meals.created_at)")
}
```

If you're looking for a particular date, you can use the following:

```
scope :for_date, -> (date) { 
  where("created_at > ?", date.beginning_of_day)
  .where("created_at < ?", date.end_of_day) 
}
```

As an example of the method being called: `current_user.meals.for_date(6.days.ago)`

Comment: How would I then implement this in my view to set `x`?

Comment: You'd use it in your controllers, for example `@last_week = current_user.meals.in_the_past_x_days(7)`

Comment: I'm not looking for a collective of days, but rather one particular date. E.g. today is Tues 22nd, I want to see the entries for Wed 16th. Is that possible?